# capacitor unable write blob to file and read it back

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I'm trying to write a blob from fetch to a file using capacitor `Filesystem.writeFile`

when I write the file this is the data I write:

[image]

...etc (you get the point full png file as a blob)

but when I read the data this is ALL the data returned
`{data: "ZumJPw=="}`

Any idea what's going on? How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post some code ?

Comment: Explain a bit more what are you doing so far please.

Comment: Hi I think the issue was not converting it to base64, I ended up solving it by using the fileTransferPlugin My issue was a collection of small bugs